# Programatically delete jobs and associated triggers in Quartz.NET

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I need a way to allow administrators to delete a job in Quartz.NET. Are there any built in methods for the JobDetail class that allow me delete the job and all associated triggers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you have to delete the job via the scheduler.

```
// First we must get a reference to a scheduler
ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);
IScheduler sched = sf.GetScheduler();

sched.DeleteJob(JobName, JobGroup);
```

Answer (score 8):

As of Today the DeleteJob method need to input JobKey as following.

```
scheduler.DeleteJob(new JobKey("JobName1", "JobGroup1"));
```